# php regex surround string with parentheses unless already surrounded by non-literal parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I have some code that is augmenting a regular expression by combining horizontal white-space and surrounding it in parentheses, unless it is already surrounded by non-backslashed parentheses. I have a piece of code that's working:

```
$regex_find = preg_replace('/(?<!\()[ \t]{2,}(?!\))/', '([ \t]{2,})', $regex_find);
```

However, for starters, the look-behind segnment, `(?<!\(`), should really allow for a literal left parenthesis, `\(`, but not a stand-alone left parenthesis, `(`.

Thanks

Comment: Adjusting from Bart's comment, we have:
`$s = '(\( ) b c d'; $s = preg_replace('/([^\t (])([ \t]{2,})([^\t )])/', '$1([ \t]{2,})$3', $s);`
Firstly, the replace does not allow for `\(` preceding the core string. And, yes, this left parenthesis would have to be single backslashed only. In addition, the right parenthesis needs to be tied into the left one. A proper solution of the above test string would be: `(\(([ \t]{2,})) b c([ \t]{2,})d`.

Comment: Actually, any odd number of backslashes preceding the inner left parenthesis would create a literal parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your original regex also has another problem. Try running it on this:

```
 $str = "asdf(     )sdf     sdf";
 //results in: "asdf( (   ) )sdf(     )sdf"
```

This regex should work:

```
$regex_find = '(    asdf(     )sdf     sdf';
preg_replace('/(?<!(\(|\s)(?=\s*\)))\s{2,}/','($0)',$regex_find);
//result = "((    )asdf(     )sdf(     )sdf"
```

---

**Edit:** Here is Qtax's solution with the additional lookbehind to ignore escaped `\(`

```
/(?<!((?<!\\)\(|\s)(?=\s*\)))\s{2,}/
```

Comment: Great! But it's not checking escapes properly, could use another lookbehind, like `/(?<!((?<!\\)\(|\s)(?=\s*\)))\s{2,}/`: http://ideone.com/4cClT vs http://ideone.com/LmvVP

Comment: Get "Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 33..." in php 4.4.9. Perhaps it's more trouble than it's worth. Nested parentheses aren't the worst thing